# Installing micropython gone wrong

Tags: installation, cmd.exe, anti-virus, pip

I am trying to install MicroPython on my computer for microprocessor programming.

I used this instruction `pip install esptool` then the cmd printed out this error:

```
Using cached esptool-4.6.2.tar.gz (262 kB)
ERROR: Error [WinError 225] Operation did not complete successfully because the file 
contains a virus or potentially unwanted software while executing command python 
setup.py egg_info
Preparing metadata (setup.py) ... error
ERROR: Could not install packages due to an OSError: [WinError 225] Operation did not 
complete successfully because the file contains a virus or potentially unwanted software
```

I removed out the block from my antivirus but the issue is still there.What should I do now?

Comment: If you have a Windows virtual machine to hand, you could install a different anti-virus in that and try the MicroPython installation. That way, you would have a reference as to where what is meant to go, and you could also check the `PATH` environment variable just in case it needs something added.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know what `pip` is doing, but you can download `esptool` from its
[Github repository](https://github.com/espressif/esptool).

I have tested the download in Windows Defender and no viruses were found.

Comment: Download in which folder?Does it matter?

Comment: I don't it matters into which folder you unpack the zip file, as long as it works in your environment.

Comment: I am using the anaconda3 as compiler do I need to unzip the folder inside the anaconda bin folder?

Comment: I'm not using anaconda3 - you'll have to test. If it's important for esptool to be in the PATH, then you need a folder that's already in it (unless you wish to add it in).

Comment: Hi which files do I need to copy out to the destination folder?espefuse,espsecure,esptool and flasher_stub right?

Comment: I don't use these utilities - I can't help with details.